# How to loop in nested loop through multiple arrays?

Tags: javascript, nested-loops

I'm trying to find and replace URL's for each a element.

Each wrap has data-folder with a path to a file.
Each `<a>` element inside each wrap links to a file. The problem is that each `<a>` can be linked with folder up, like '../' or multiple- '../../../'.
I have to check how many '../' each  has and for each '../' remove one folder. like '/folder/'

This is my HTML:

```
<div class="wrap" data-folder="data_folder_1/data_folder_2/data_folder_3/">
  <a href="/folder1/folder1/_WAS_Modeller_DNK1.htm">Link</a>
  <a href="../folder1/folder2/Modeller.htm">Link</a>
  <a href="../../folder1/folder2/Modeller.htm">Link</a>
</div>

<div class="wrap" data-folder="data_folder_1/data_folder_2/data_folder_3/data_folder_4">
  <a href="../folder1/folder2/folder3/Specifikationer.htm">Link</a>
</div>
```

And jQuery:

```
console.clear();

var wrap = $(".wrap");

$.each(wrap, function(index, value) {
  var file = $(this).attr("data-folder");
  var fileArray = file.split("/");
  var links = $(this).find("a");

  // loop for link elements (a), it looops 4 times in this case
  $.each( links, function( ind, val ){
    var $this = $(this);
    var aHref = $(this).attr('href');
    var hrToArr = aHref.split("/");
    console.log(hrToArr);

    $.each(hrToArr, function( indx, va ){
      if( va == '..' ){
        fileArray.pop();
        $this.addClass( fileArray );
        console.log(va);
      }
    });
  })
});
```

The results should be:

```
<div class="wrap" data-folder="data_folder_1/data_folder_2/data_folder_3">
  <a href="data_folder_1/data_folder_2/data_folder_3/folder1/folder1/_WAS_Modeller_DNK1.htm">Link</a>
  <a href="data_folder_1/data_folder_2/folder1/folder2/Modeller.htm">Link</a>
  <a href="data_folder_1/folder1/folder2/Modeller.htm">Link</a>
</div>

<div class="wrap" data-folder="data_folder_1/data_folder_2/data_folder_3/data_folder_4">
  <a href="data_folder_1/data_folder_2/data_folder_3/folder1/folder2/folder3/Specifikationer.htm">Link</a>
</div>
```

Codepen here: https://codepen.io/rolandas/pen/XLEXPR?editors=1010

Comment: You know that browsers are able to handle relative URLs, right? If you want that third link with `href="../../folder1/folder2/Modeller.htm"` to actually point to `data_folder_1/folder1/folder2/Modeller.htm` - then all you need to do, is add that prefix into the href attribute content, `href="data_folder_1/data_folder_2/data_folder_3/../../folder1/folder2/Modeller.htm"` - no need to manually replace any `../` and keep count how many, etc.

Comment: @04FS yes, I know, but I'll have to check for ID by that generated URL

Comment: Don’t know what you mean by that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var wrap = $(".wrap");

$.each(wrap, function(index, value) {
  var file = $(this).attr("data-folder");
  var fileArray = file.split("/").filter(Boolean);
  var links = $(this).find("a");

  // loop for link elements (a), it looops 4 times in this case
  $.each( links, function( ind, val ){
    var $this = $(this);
    var aHref = $(this).attr('href');
    var hrToArr = aHref.split("/").filter(Boolean);
    /* console.log(hrToArr) */;
    let a = fileArray;
    let b = [];
    $.each(hrToArr, function( indx, va ){
        if(va === '..') {
        fileArray.pop();
      } else {
      b.push(va)
      }
    });
    $this.attr('href', a.concat(b).join('/'));
  })
});
```

Output:

```
<div class="wrap" data-folder="data_folder_1/data_folder_2/data_folder_3/">
  <a href="data_folder_1/data_folder_2/data_folder_3/folder1/folder1/_WAS_Modeller_DNK1.htm">Link</a>
  <a href="data_folder_1/data_folder_2/folder1/folder2/Modeller.htm">Link</a>
  <a href="folder1/folder2/Modeller.htm">Link</a>
</div>

<div class="wrap" data-folder="data_folder_1/data_folder_2/data_folder_3/data_folder_4">
  <a href="data_folder_1/data_folder_2/data_folder_3/folder1/folder2/folder3/Specifikationer.htm">Link</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you offer a written explanation too, please?  (As opposed to just replying with only code.)

Comment: @sreeram there is no written explanation, but I get the result I was expecting

Comment: Give me a moment while I refactor it and add explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you don't need to remove `../` because servers/browsers usually support finding subdirectory in url (e.g `/a/b/../c` will be interpret as `/a/c`). However I do it in below code

```
let w=[...document.querySelectorAll('.wrap')];

for(let v of w) {  
  let f = v.dataset.folder.split('/');
  for(let a of [...v.children]) {
    let n= a.outerHTML.match(/href="(.*)">/)[1].match(/\.\.\//g);
    n = n ? n.length : 0;
    let p= n==0 ? f : f.slice(0,-n||1);
    a.href = p.join('/') + a.pathname.replace(/\.\.\//g,'');
  }
}
```

```js
let w=[...document.querySelectorAll('.wrap')];

for(let v of w) {  
  let f = v.dataset.folder.split('/');
  for(let a of [...v.children]) {
    let n= a.outerHTML.match(/href="(.*)">/)[1].match(/\.\.\//g);
    n = n ? n.length : 0;
    let p= n==0 ? f : f.slice(0,-n||1);
    a.href = p.join('/') + a.pathname.replace(/\.\.\//g,'');
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap" data-folder="data_folder_1/data_folder_2/data_folder_3">
  <a href="/folder1/folder1/_WAS_Modeller_DNK1.htm">Link</a>
  <a href="../folder1/folder2/Modeller.htm">Link</a>
  <a href="../../folder1/folder2/Modeller.htm">Link</a>
</div>

<div class="wrap" data-folder="data_folder_1/data_folder_2/data_folder_3/data_folder_4">
  <a href="../folder1/folder2/folder3/Specifikationer.htm">Link</a>
</div>
```